# Twilio SMS wrong encoding in Java API

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, sms, twilio

Supposedly, twilio handles encoding automatically... but it doesn't.
My code is as in the tutorial:

```
String msg = "áéíóú";
Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(toNumber),
                new PhoneNumber(fromNumber),
                msg).create();
```

But in the phone, the message arrives with the infamous � characters

I have tried changing the JVM locale parameters:

-Duser.language=es -Duser.region=MX

to no avail

I'm testing in a Linux box.  On my colleague's Windows 10 box works fine.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and currently have a ticket opened with Twilio Support on this.

I took a chance and tried the previous version of their API and it worked without a hitch.

Use maven to grab the 6.3.0 version of their Java API or download it from their [Java API Page](http://twilio.com/docs/java/install) however they note that version 6.x is deprecated.  Hopefully this will be addressed in an update to their API.

[Example Code for sending Messages with the 6.3.0 version of Twilio's Java API](https://twilio.radicalskills.com/library/sms-send-tech-specs.html)